# How can I write Platform specific code in a Flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code, which I want to make available as a pub or a package to other Flutter projects. But this code makes use of some native android code in Kotlin.
In a Flutter application, we have both iOS and Android folders, so we can easily write native code there. But in case of a plugin or a package, there are no iOS and Android folders, so I'm confused how can we implement native code in a package.

Comment: Although, there are hidden .android and .iOS folder instead, in case of package, but these are auto-generated it seems, as they get reformed everytime we build the app.

Comment: Did you [create a "Flutter plugin" project](https://www.loom.com/share/7f72cbe3e67147b797cc903b7a5cf9b3)?

Comment: I tried both "--template=package" and "--template=plugin", but none of them has those iOS or android folders.

Comment: Have you tried creating the project using Android Studio?

Comment: Yes, just now, I'm confused, when I tried creating a plugin using terminal command, it didn't show iOS/android folders, but when I created it using Android studio, it shows, How?

Comment: Can you provide your Flutter command when creating the "plugin" template?

Comment: This is the command :- flutter create --template=plugin sampleplugin

Comment: Based from the [doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#step-1-create-the-package-1), you should provide the `--platforms=` option.

Comment: Yeah, now I get it. Will read the docs better next time. Thanks a lot man. @rickimaru

Comment: Glad that I could help. Good luck!